# Installing cookbook on RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rubymine, cookbook

I am trying to import a folder(open directory) on Ruby Mine but when I do it says "Install missing gems" Everytime I click on it, it installs some and then again gives the same error.
I have Mac OS X 10.7.

Here is the error:

```
/Users/Vinisa/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/bin/bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Using rake (0.9.2) 
Using multi_json (1.0.3) 
Using activesupport (3.1.0) 
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using activemodel (3.1.0) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.3.2) 
Using rack-cache (1.0.3) 
Using rack-mount (0.8.3) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.0.0) 
Using actionpack (3.1.0) 
Using mime-types (1.16) 
Using polyglot (0.3.2) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.3.0) 
Using actionmailer (3.1.0) 
Using arel (2.2.1) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.29) 
Using activerecord (3.1.0) 
Using activeresource (3.1.0) 
Using ansi (1.3.0) 
Using bundler (1.0.18) 
Installing nokogiri (1.5.0) with native extensions /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:551:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

        /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... no
-----
libiconv is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/Vinisa/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/bin/ruby
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-iconv-dir
    --with-iconv-include
    --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
    --with-iconv-lib
    --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
    --with-xml2-dir
    --without-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include
    --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
    --with-xslt-dir
    --without-xslt-dir
    --with-xslt-include
    --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
    --with-xslt-lib
    --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
    --with-iconvlib
    --without-iconvlib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:504:in `each'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:504:in `build_extensions'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:180:in `install'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/source.rb:101:in `install'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:78:in `preserve_paths'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/source.rb:91:in `install'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/installer.rb:58:in `run'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:93:in `with_build_args'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/installer.rb:57:in `run'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/installer.rb:49:in `run'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/cli.rb:220:in `install'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/bundler-1.0.18/bin/bundle:13
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/bin/bundle:19
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any thoughts on why so?

After installing novigiri, I am getting the following error:

```
/Users/Vinisa/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Assorted Mix/OOLS'11/OOLS-Lect/barik-csc517_cookbook3-325ff9f/script/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
/Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load': /Assorted Mix/OOLS'11/OOLS-Lect/barik-csc517_cookbook3-325ff9f/config/initializers/session_store.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end (SyntaxError)
...sion_store :cookie_store, key: '_cookbook3_session'
                              ^
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:555
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:554:in `each'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:554
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:92:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Assorted Mix/OOLS'11/OOLS-Lect/barik-csc517_cookbook3-325ff9f/config/environment.rb:5
    from /Assorted Mix/OOLS'11/OOLS-Lect/barik-csc517_cookbook3-325ff9f/config.ru:4:in `require'
    from /Assorted Mix/OOLS'11/OOLS-Lect/barik-csc517_cookbook3-325ff9f/config.ru:4
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/Vinisa/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Assorted Mix/OOLS'11/OOLS-Lect/barik-csc517_cookbook3-325ff9f/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /Assorted Mix/OOLS'11/OOLS-Lect/barik-csc517_cookbook3-325ff9f/config.ru:1
Exiting

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: It tries to install gems with a native part in it, so it has to compile something. Have you checked if libiconv is in your library path? Have you checked http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html what the dependencies are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installation of the Nokogiri gem is failing.

Try installing it manually for Mac OS @ [Why does installing Nokogiri on Mac OS fail with libiconv is missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528839/installing-nokogiri-fails-libiconv-missing)

Comment: Hey I have edited my question, after installing novigiri, I am getting the another error. It says syntax error, I tried to fix it but its throwing more errors now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you start the project by command line? It could be related with your ruby version.

Check this [file](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-devise-rspec-cucumber/blob/master/config/initializers/session_store.rb) and see if yours have the same syntax.