# in `require': no such file to load -- iconv (LoadError) 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, rvm, iconv

```
    ➜  expertiza git:(master) ✗ ruby -v
    ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-darwin11.1.0]
    ➜  expertiza git:(master) ✗ rails -v
    Rails 2.3.14
    ➜  expertiza git:(master) ✗ script/server
/Users/HPV/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:3:in `require': no such file to load -- iconv (LoadError)
    from /Users/HPV/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:3
    from /Users/HPV/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext/integer/inflections.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/HPV/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext/integer/inflections.rb:1
    from /Users/HPV/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext/integer.rb:2:in `require'
    from /Users/HPV/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext/integer.rb:2
    from /Users/HPV/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:8:in `require'
    from /Users/HPV/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:8
    from /Users/HPV/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:8:in `each'
    from /Users/HPV/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:8
    from /Users/HPV/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support.rb:56:in `require'
    from /Users/HPV/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support.rb:56
    from /Users/HPV/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/commands/server.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/HPV/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/commands/server.rb:1
    from script/server:3:in `require'
```

I have tried installing

```
rvm pkg install readline
rvm pkg install iconv
rvm install 1.8.7
rvm use 1.8.7
```

Even tried [Why does installing Nokogiri on Mac OS fail with libiconv is missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528839/installing-nokogiri-fails-libiconv-missing).

Nothing works. Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It shows that the iconv not exist but the iconv has installed in my production env.

```
root@AY130/current# iconv --version
iconv (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.15-0ubuntu10.4) 2.15
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Ulrich Drepper.
```

To resolve it, add this in your Gemfile:

```
gem "iconv", "~> 1.0.3"
```

Then run `bundle install`.

Note: iconv has been deprecated for a while. It is replaced by (builtin) String#encode
See here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=160369

Comment: Specifying the iconv gem worked for me on Ruby 2.0.0. Thanks!

Comment: Much better than recompiling, that took forever :)

Comment: This does not work for me. I get the error `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command iconv,`

Answer (score 7):

For those using [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) instead of rvm

```
$ which iconv
$ /usr/local/bin/iconv
```

Then use the directory location of iconv to reinstall ruby

```
$ CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-iconv-dir=/usr/local" rbenv install 1.8.7-p358
```

Good luck

(As a side note, this error has been reported to happen in Ruby 1.8.7-p3xx)