# Redmine on Passenger (nginx) won't start

Tags: ruby, nginx, passenger, redmine

I followed the following tutorial:
http://redminecrm.com/boards/4/topics/448-installing-redmine-2-2-passenger-nginx-rvm-on-ubuntu-12-04

At first, I had problems with mysql2 but fixed it by editing the Gemfile and running a bundle update. After which, I ran into a new problem. Attached below is the traceback. I hope someone could help me with this one.

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0p0, passenger-4.0.0.rc6, nginx 1.2.7.

```
No such file to load -- iconv (LoadError)
  /var/data/redmine/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `rescue in depend_on'
  /var/data/redmine/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:312:in `depend_on'
  /var/data/redmine/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
  /var/data/redmine/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
  /var/data/redmine/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
  /var/data/redmine/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
  /var/data/redmine/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
  /var/data/redmine/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
  /var/data/redmine/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
  /var/data/redmine/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /var/data/redmine/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  /var/data/redmine/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /var/data/redmine/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
  /var/data/redmine/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  /var/data/redmine/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
  /var/data/redmine/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  /var/data/redmine/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /var/data/redmine/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
  /var/data/redmine/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/passenger-4.0.0.rc6/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:82:in `eval'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/passenger-4.0.0.rc6/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:82:in `preload_app'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/passenger-4.0.0.rc6/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:127:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/passenger-4.0.0.rc6/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:6:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/passenger-4.0.0.rc6/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the logs !

> No such file to load -- iconv (LoadError)

Install iconv on your system, then install the iconv gem

```
gem install iconv
```

Answer (score 0):

[in `require': no such file to load -- iconv (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829886/in-require-no-such-file-to-load-iconv-loaderror/19332909#19332909)

I have resolve it:

> It shows that the iconv not exist but the iconv has installed in my production env.

root@AY130/current# iconv --version

iconv (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.15-0ubuntu10.4) 2.15

Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO

warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Written by Ulrich Drepper.

How to resolve it:

install

> gem "iconv", "~> 1.0.3" #added this in your Gemfile

iconv has been deprecated for a while. It is replaced by (builtin) String#encode

> see here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=160369

others:

> [in `require': no such file to load -- iconv (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829886/in-require-no-such-file-to-load-iconv-loaderror)