# "in `require': cannot load such file -- iconv (LoadError)"

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I installed ruby 2.2.0 on Ubuntu 64-bit 14.04 to my home following  https://railssavvy.wordpress.com/2012/06/02/install_ruby_and_rails/, and then installed a package called `pdfbeads`. When I run the package, I have this error:

```
$ /home/t/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/wrappers/pdfbeads -o all.pdf
/home/t/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- iconv (LoadError)
    from /home/t/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/t/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/pdfbeads-1.1.1/bin/pdfbeads:35:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/t/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/pdfbeads:23:in `load'
    from /home/t/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/pdfbeads:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/t/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/t/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

To solve the problem, I followed this reply https://stackoverflow.com/a/19332909/156458,

```
$ which iconv
/usr/bin/iconv

$ iconv --version
iconv (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.6) 2.19
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Ulrich Drepper.

$ gem "iconv", "~> 1.0.3"
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command iconv,
```

So what happens to ruby and iconv? What shall I do now? Many thanks!

---

I have installed both 2.1.0 and 2.0.0 and `pdfbeads` under them respectively. But when I run `pdfbeads` located under their `wrappers` directories, I still have the same error:

```
in `require': cannot load such file -- iconv (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error:

> ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- iconv (LoadError)

says that the ruby Standard Library module `iconv` cannot be found.  That's because `iconv` no longer exists in ruby's Standard Library in ruby 2.2.

The line:

```
gem "iconv", "~> 1.0.3"
```

is supposed to go in a Gemfile, which is a file that is created when you create a rails project.  In a rails project, you install all the gems listed in your Gemfile using Bundler, e.g.:

```
$ bundle install
```

Comment: Thanks. Does `pdfbeads` still depends on `iconv`? Is `iconv` it needs different from `/usr/bin/iconv`? How can I put `gem "iconv", "~> 1.0.3"`
 in my Gemfile? I didn't create a rails project, I think? I only installed a package called `pdfbeads`. Where shall I run `bundle install`?

Comment: *is iconv it needs different from /usr/bin/iconv* --  Yes.  Your system has a command called iconv, which is not the same thing as a module in ruby's Standard Library.   You system has no idea that ruby has even been invented.  Whoever wrote the iconv module in ruby's Standard Library was obviously familiar with the Unix command iconv, and named the ruby module with the same name.

Comment: Under which directory, shall I run `bundle install`? I got the error `Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory` when I run it.

Comment: I am not sure why you are following rails instructions to use pdfbeads.  pdfbeads was written a long time ago, and it relies on ruby having a module called iconv in the ruby Standard Library, so if you want to use the pdfbeads module, you will need to install an old version of ruby, e.g. ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: The latest pdfbeads is 1.1.1 - January 30, 2014. is it not so long ago?

Comment: Actually, you can install ruby 2.0 if you want to use pdfbeads.

Comment: Thanks. How did you find ruby 2.0 out?

Comment: I looked at the ruby 2.0.0 Standard Library, and it has the iconv module.  See here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/

Comment: *The latest pdfbeads is 1.1.1 - January 30, 2014. is it not so long ago?* Let me see if I can install it with ruby 2.2.

Comment: I have installed both ruby 2.0.0 and 2.1.0, and when I run pdfbeads, it always say `in `require': cannot load such file -- iconv (LoadError)`. What shall I do?

Comment: I installed 1.9.3, and pdfbeads, and when running its pdfbeads, it seems no problem now.  But isn't `iconv` in 2.0.0 ? Last year,  I installed pdfbeads on 2.1.0, and it rans well. Why does it not work on 2.0.0 and on 2.1.0 this time?

Comment: @Tim, When I run the following program: `require 'iconv'` in ruby 2.0, I get the error you get.  In ruby 1.9.3, I get a warning: `'require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.`  I was unable to install pdfbeads in ruby 2.2 because I couldn't install imagemagik.  *The latest pdfbeads is 1.1.1 - January 30, 2014. is it not so long ago?* No it isn't.  Maybe you should try emailing the author.

Answer (score 1):

```
gem install iconv
```

fixed the issue for me