# How to have Rails migrations run automatically on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, migration, rails-migrations

I have more than 10 different Ruby on Rails apps where I have to deploy the same code. I have connected the git repo to my Heroku apps, so whenever I push new changes it deploys on all of them.

The issue is with the database migration step. I want to run migrations automatically after each deployment. None of custom build pack is working. Can someone please help me? I am using rails 4 and spree.

**So far, I have tried:**

1. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
2. https://github.com/gunpowderlabs/buildpack-ruby-db-migrate.git

**This solution is not working.**

**Is there any other solution to run Rails migrations on Heroku automatically?**

Comment: the log says the it can't find file `iconv`, have you checked that?

Comment: when i remove buidpack everything start working fine.my deployment done successfully. question is i want to run migration auto?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No need to use gems or write scripts. 
Heroku have a 'release' phase features (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase).

Thank to this, you just have to add to your `Procfile` some code to automatically run `rake db:migrate` to all your push :

**Procfile (root app)**

```
release: rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Travis-ci](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/heroku/). Pretty simple to setup and provides the desired functionality

Answer (score -1):

Add `gem 'iconv', '~> 1.0.3'` to your gemfile and then try it will work as worked for me!

I take this as a duplicate of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829886/in-require-no-such-file-to-load-iconv-loaderror)

If you are looking for alternative then you can write a deploy script in .sh file and run it everytime like bash script.

Comment: Originally i want to run migration auto on heroku after deployment

Comment: yes iconv is like a dependency, have you tried the solution ? it should work fine.

Comment: How does that relates to migrations? If somehow that gem runs migrations, it's a side effect no one should expect or know of. So this should never be the solution to the problem. @Gregdebrick solution works properly and is the correct answer