# cannot load such file -- iconv ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, web-deployment, iconv

I've got a problem when trying to deploy old project, using command:

> ruby script/server -e production -p 999

As result:

```
D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require': cannot load such file -- iconv (LoadError)
    from D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require'
    from D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/core_ext/integer/inflections.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/core_ext/integer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:8:in `each'
    from D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support.rb:56:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rails-2.3.10/lib/commands/server.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from script/server:3:in `<main>'
```

My versions are:

> Ruby -v

```
D:\InstantRails\rails_apps\TestManager>ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x64-mingw32]
```

> Gem -v

```
2.6.7
```

The result of iconv gem installation:

> gem install iconv -- --with-iconv-include=D:/iconv/include --with-iconv-lib=D:/iconv/lib

result:

```
    Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-iconv-include=D:/iconv/include --with-iconv-lib=D:/iconv/lib'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing iconv:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/iconv-1.0.4/ext/iconv
D:/InstantRails/ruby/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20161021-4952-wjxi9k.rb extconf.rb --with-iconv-include=D:/iconv/include --with-iconv-lib=D:/iconv/lib
checking for rb_enc_get() in ruby/encoding.h... yes
checking for rb_sys_fail_str() in ruby.h... yes
checking for iconv() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv() in -liconv... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=D:/InstantRails/ruby/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-iconv-dir
        --without-iconv-dir
        --with-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
        --with-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
        --enable-config-charset
        --disable-config-charset
        --with-config-charset
        --without-config-charset
        --with-iconvlib
        --without-iconvlib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/iconv-1.0.4/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/iconv-1.0.4 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/iconv-1.0.4/gem_make.out
```

Comment: I am not on Windows so I can't help with it. Try to find it on SO.

Comment: Do you have devkit installed to build native libraries ? http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have `iconv` gem installed.
Check out similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19332909/3475678).

Comment: I've tried to install it using that advise, but there are next error with native libraries

Comment: checking for rb_enc_get() in ruby/encoding.h... yes
checking for rb_sys_fail_str() in ruby.h... yes
checking for iconv() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv() in -liconv... no

Comment: I'm using gem install iconv -- --with-iconv-include=D:/iconv/include --with-iconv-lib=D:/iconv/lib

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing Devkit for windows: http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/

Also note that you should install devkit in the same arch as you installed ruby (ie: both 64bit version) - ppl often install one 32 and one 64 version and that causes errors too.

Good luck