# Brew update failed: untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge

Tags: homebrew

Trying to update Homebrew with `brew update` I got the following error

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwrittenby merge:     
 Library/Formula/argp-standalone.rb
 Library/Formula/cocot.rb 
Please move or remove them before you can merge. 
Aborting 
Updating e088818..5909e2c 
Error: Failed while executing git pull  origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

I found a blog post by someone who experienced a similar problem after having installed Mountain Lion (which I did this week too). He explains how he removed the files referred to in the error message

```
I removed these files:
$ cd $(brew --prefix)
$ rm cocot.rb
However, removing these files didn't help with the brew update. Instead I had to manually update brew through git:
$ cd $(brew --prefix)
$ git fetch origin
$ git reset --hard origin/master
$ brew update
Already up-to-date.
```

Assuming those instructions are correct (which I maybe shouldn't assume), I tried to follow these instructions and do

```
    $ cd $(brew --prefix)
    $ rm cocot.rb
```

However, it said 'file doesn't exist' when I tried to rm cocot.rb

One thing I'm not sure about is the `cd $(brew --prefix)` Are those the exact words I type or do I have to replace prefix with something? the cd was successful, so I'm assuming it was correct -- it moved me into /usr/local, but there was no file to remove. Contents of /usr/local are

```
Cellar              clamXav             git             mysql               var Library             doc             heroku              mysql-5.5.15-osx10.6-x86_64 README.md           etc             include             rvm bin             foreman             lib             share
```

At any rate, do you know how I can fix the 'brew update'

Update: After removing the files according to favoretti's instructions and trying `chown -R <your_username> $(brew --prefix)/.git`, I got the following error running `brew update`

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    Library/Aliases/gperftools
    Library/Aliases/hashdeep
    Library/Aliases/htop
    Library/Aliases/nodejs
    Library/Aliases/ocio
    Library/Aliases/oiio
    Library/Aliases/pgrep
    Library/Aliases/pkill
    Library/Aliases/qt4
    Library/Aliases/twolame
    Library/Aliases/wxwidgets
    Library/Contributions/cmds/brew-aspell-dictionaries
    Library/Contributions/cmds/brew-beer.rb
    Library/Contributions/cmds/brew-dirty.rb
    Library/Contributions/cmds/brew-graph
    Library/Contributions/cmds/brew-grep
    Library/Contributions/cmds/brew-leaves.rb
    Library/Contributions/cmds/brew-linkapps.rb
    Library/Contributions/cmds/brew-ls-taps.rb
    Library/Contributions/cmds/brew-man
    Library/Contributions/cmds/brew-md5-to-sha1
    Library/Contributions/cmds/brew-mirror-check.rb
    Library/Contributions/cmds/brew-pull.rb
    Library/Contributions/cmds/brew-readall.rb
    Library/Contributions/cmds/brew-server
    Library/Contributions/cmds/brew-services.rb
    Library/Contributions/cmds/brew-switch.rb
    Library/Contributions/cmds/brew-test-bot.rb
    Library/Contributions/cmds/brew-tests.rb
    Library/Contributions/cmds/brew-unpack.rb
    Library/Contributions/cmds/brew-which.rb
    Library/Contributions/cmds/git
    Library/Contributions/cmds/svn
    Library/ENV/4.3/apr-1-config
    Library/ENV/4.3/bsdmake
    Library/ENV/4.3/c++
    Library/ENV/4.3/c89
    Library/ENV/4.3/c99
    Library/ENV/4.3/cc
    Library/ENV/4.3/clang
    Library/ENV/4.3/clang++
    Library/ENV/4.3/cpp
    Library/ENV/4.3/g++
    Library/ENV/4.3/gcc
    Library/ENV/4.3/git
    Library/ENV/4.3/i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2
    Library/ENV/4.3/i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2
    Library/ENV/4.3/ld
    Library/ENV/4.3/llvm-g++
    Library/ENV/4.3/llvm-g++-4.2
    Library/ENV/4.3/llvm-gcc
    Library/ENV/4.3/llvm-gcc-4.2
    Library/ENV/4.3/make
    Library/ENV/4.3/mig
    Library/ENV/4.3/sed
    Library/ENV/4.3/svn
    Library/ENV/4.3/xcrun
    Library/ENV/libsuperenv.rb
    Library/ENV/pkgconfig/leopard/libcrypto.pc
    Library/ENV/pkgconfig/leopard/libcurl.pc
    Library/ENV/pkgconfig/mountain_lion/libcurl.pc
    Library/ENV/pkgconfig/mountain_lion/libexslt.pc
    Library/ENV/pkgconfig/mountain_lion/libxml-2.0.pc
    Library/ENV/pkgconfig/mountain_lion/libxslt.pc
    Library/Formula/abcl.rb
    Library/Formula/abcmidi.rb
    Library/Formula/aiccu.rb
    Library/Formula/akka.rb
    Library/Formula/alac.rb
    Library/Formula/alure.rb
    Library/Formula/appledoc.rb
    Library/Formula/arangodb.rb
    Library/Formula/argp-standalone.rb
    Library/Formula/argtable.rb
    Library/Formula/autopano-sift-c.rb
    Library/Formula/avian.rb
    Library/Formula/avidemux.rb
    Library/Formula/avro-cpp.rb
    Library/Formula/aws-cloudsearch.rb
    Library/Formula/aws-sns-cli.rb
    Library/Formula/backupninja.rb
    Library/Formula/bact.rb
    Library/Formula/bam.rb
    Library/Formula/basex.rb
    Library/Formula/berkeley-db4.rb
    Library/Formula/bind.rb
    Library/Formula/blazeblogger.rb
    Library/Formula/bochs.rb
    Library/Formula/boost149.rb
    Library/Formula/bsdconv.rb
    Library/Formula/bsdmake.rb
    Library/Formula/buildapp.rb
    Library/Formula/bup.rb
    Library/Formula/byacc.rb
    Library/Formula/cadubi.rb
    Library/Formula/camellia.rb
    Library/Formula/casperjs.rb
    Library/Formula/ccextractor.rb
    Library/Formula/cconv.rb
    Library/Formula/cdo.rb
    Library/Formula/cdpr.rb
    Library/Formula/cgvg.rb
    Library/Formula/checkstyle.rb
    Library/Formula/chordii.rb
    Library/Formula/chruby.rb
    Library/Formula/cifer.rb
    Library/Formula/clhep.rb
    Library/Formula/cntlm.rb
    Library/Formula/cocot.rb
    Library/Formula/cogl.rb
    Library/Formula/collada-dom.rb
    Library/Formula/crash.rb
    Library/Formula/crossroads.rb
    Library/Formula/crosstool-ng.rb
    Library/Formula/css-crush.rb
    Library/Formula/csync.rb
    Library/Formula/ctemplate.rb
    Library/Formula/curlftpfs.rb
    Library/Formula/cutter.rb
    Library/Formula/cvsutils.rb
    Library/Formula/darkstat.rb
    Library/Formula/darner.rb
    Library/Formula/dart.rb
    Library/Formula/dasm.rb
    Library/Formula/debianutils.rb
    Library/Formula/dfc.rb
    Library/Formula/dgtal.rb
    Library/Formula/dhcping.rb
    Library/Formula/di.rb
    Library/Formula/dmtx-utils.rb
    Library/Formula/drip.rb
    Library/Formula/dsniff.rb
    Library/Fo
Aborting
Updating e088818..c1fbc29
Error: Failed while executing git pull  origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762859/brew-update-the-following-untracked-working-tree-files-would-be-overwritten-by

Comment: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core - check the official README.md of Homebrew Core. There should be no need to adjust permissions as a few of the older answers recommend. Also check that you are pointed to the current official source url. More info in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113427/brew-update-failed-untracked-working-tree-files-would-be-overwritten-by-merge/40599893?s=2|2.2654#40599893

Answer (score 280, accepted):

```
cd $(brew --prefix)
git reset --hard HEAD
brew update
```

Comment: Had similar issue to the original question but with different conflicting files. Just resetting was sufficient to let me update and resolve the issue.

Comment: you might want to do also ``git add .`` followed by ``git stash`` :P

Comment: Works for me. Literally type this cd $(brew --prefix)

Comment: If, after changing to the brew directory with `cd $(brew --prefix)` and resetting the git stage with `git reset --hard HEAD` your `git status` does not return working directory clean you may also need to clean up the state by running `git clean -df`.

Comment: Instead of `git reset --hard HEAD` (which wouldn't work for me), I did `git fetch --all` and `git reset --hard origin/master`

Comment: I had a lot of deleted files, I did git add -u and then the rest of the code above.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks. (OSX 10 Yosemite ```10.10.2```).

Comment: I did need to sudo the `git reset --hard HEAD`, but in the end it worked, thanx!

Comment: @Kevin. I get fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'origin/master'

Comment: for me `git clean -f` worked as there were many untracked files

Answer (score 359):

You need to do the following:

```
cd $(brew --prefix)
rm Library/Formula/argp-standalone.rb
rm Library/Formula/cocot.rb
```

And then do the

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
brew update
```

Basically, to explain a bit more:

```
cd $(brew --prefix)
```

tells `cd` to change the directory to whatever `brew --prefix` will output. 
If you try executing `brew --prefix` command you should see something in lines of:

```
brew --prefix
/usr/local
```

So the command would be in this case an equivalent of `cd /usr/local`.
Newer `brew` versions have formulae under its installation prefix and `Library/Formula/`, so that's where you need to look for those outdated/changed files.

Note, that if you changed those formulae yourself for a particular reason (like pinning a version) this action will revert them back to default ones and may produce unwanted effects.

@TedPennings noted in comments that this worked for him, but his sequence was:

1. chown everything to `my_username:admin`, ie, `sudo chown -R ted:admin $(brew --prefix)`
2. run the two git commands above,`git fetch origin` and `git reset --hard origin/master`

Comment: when I did git reset --hard origin/master, it seemed to only partially work. This is the output. error: unable to unlink old '.gitignore' (Permission denied)
error: unable to create file CONTRIBUTING.md (Permission denied)
Checking out files: 100% (2493/2493), done.
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'origin/master'.

Comment: It means your permissions are screwed. One way would be to run `sudo git reset --hard`, other and a better way would be to fix permissions and do `chown -R <your_username> $(brew --prefix)/.git`

Comment: This is how permissions on my brew prefix look like here: `drwxrwxr-x  16 root  admin  646 Dec 27 20:30 /usr/local/`

Comment: Basically all directories belong to 'admin' group (which your user by default belongs to) and group has read-write permissions on everything brew-related

Comment: I did chown -R <your_username> $(brew --prefix)/.git but got the same fail message on brew update. Do you know what I check what the permissions are to see if they look like yours?

Comment: You did replace <your_username> with your username, right? :) Other than that, you need to fix the permissions to your user for every file that you get Permission denied for.

Comment: This solution fixed things for me, but I had to chown everything to my username:admin, ie, `sudo chown -R ted:admin $(brew --prefix)` and then run the two git commands above, `git fetch origin` and `git reset --hard origin/master`

Comment: @TedPennings: Cool! I'll add your commands to the answer as a possible additional step.

Comment: Well that broke my brew even worse.-MacBook-Pro-2:local $ brew update
Error: /usr/local must be writable! To fix it run as SU.

Comment: @StarWind what exactly did you do?

Comment: I wasn't running as SU.

Comment: It's worth noting that you may not need to change permissions and move directories manually. See answer below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/40599893/5440638), for example.

Answer (score 46):

This is caused by an old bug in the `update` code that has long since been fixed. However, the nature of the bug requires that you do the following:

```
cd $(brew --repository)
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

If `brew doctor` still complains about uncommitted modifications, also run this command:

```
cd $(brew --repository)    
git clean -fd
```

Comment: This solution worked for me when the accepted answer did not.

Answer (score 31):

```
$ cd $(brew --prefix)
$ git clean -fd
$ git reset --hard
$ sudo chown -R `whoami` `brew --prefix`
$ brew update
```

Note: steps 2&3 worked for me since I did step 5 before 4 before I got the error. The *brew update* before changing the owner of the folder caused the whole problem.

Comment: This worked for me. I would like to add that this is can be caused by other programs installing stuff in `/usr/local` with other permissions. For me it was MacPGP that installed itself with root privileges.

Comment: This fixed it for me after upgrading to Mac OS X 10.11 messed with `/usr/local`'s permissions. Thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting that you may not need to change permissions and move directories manually. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/40599893/5440638, for example.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue where my brew package library got downloaded as a root user and then I was not able to run brew update as git would complain about not able to merge the file.

Solution was to do :-

```
sudo chown -R <user> /usr/local/Library
```

Answer (score 5):

Resetting the brew repository should be the most efficient way if you don't mind to discard potential modifications on formulas you might have been applied:

```
$ cd `brew --prefix`
$ git fetch origin
$ git reset --hard origin/master
$ brew cleanup --force
$ brew update
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix this on my machine by adding admin group write (and setgid bit) permission at these paths:

```
sudo chmod -R g+ws /usr/local /Library/Caches/Homebrew
```

The s sets the group id on execution so that the write permissions aren't lost the next time a different admin user updates or upgrades Homebrew.

This answer is somewhat incomplete because when I try to do `brew cleanup --force` there is a permissions issue when Homebrew tries to remove content in /usr/local/Cellar/. (Unfortunately I'm not able to investigate this further at the moment.)

Comment: There is a popular script written to fix Homebrew permissions that apparently works quite well. I haven't needed to use it myself; I manually did the changes :) But this may help others: https://gist.github.com/rpavlik/768518

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to just use `git stash`.

The brew update command performs a `git pull`, so if there are any changed files (or even file attributes, which happened to me when I changed permissions in the directory recursively) you have to somehow fix the conflicts. Using `git stash` is one way; it takes any changes and puts them aside so you effectively revert to the last updated repo version. The Homebrew 'location' is by default `/usr/local` and it installs as a git repository. You can look for a `.git` folder to see for yourself. I'm writing a homebrew uninstall script to be posted on my GitHub profile soon with more info.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo chown -R USER /usr/local/bin
```

note - for USER use command whom i.e. your username

```
sudo brew doctor
```

Comment: or to generalize:  `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/bin` where adding the `$` posits the USER env variable, which holds the current USERname.

Answer (score 1):

This approach may be simpler than some. It involves:

- fixing a git issue so you can delegate management of changes to it again.
- no manual moves of files or directories.
- no manual adjustments of file or directory permissions.

Steps (with notes for those who want explanations):

```
cd $(brew --repository)                              // see Note 1 below
git remote add brew https://github.com/Homebrew/brew // see Note 2 below
git pull brew master                                 // promising fast-forward report!
brew update                                          // see Note 3 below
```

Overview:
From what I can tell, the actual cause of this issue is a change in the repo url. It's now `brew` and was `brew.git`. (Full up-to-date url: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew)

Note 1: This first command takes you from anywhere in your file structure to the correct directory. The directory structure is different for me than what others show above (Mac OS 10.11.16), but with this command, those differences should not matter.

Note 2: This second command adds the correct remote url to a new alias; I did so just in case this approach didn't accomplish what I wanted and I needed the previous address again. Since the new remote worked, I'll invite someone else to comment on simply changing the url aliased by origin. I'll happily update the answer to reflect what worked for you.

Note 3: This forth command has exactly the desired result: it reports a large number of updates, including the particularly nice report of "==> Migrated HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY to /usr/local/Homebrew!" (emphasis theirs).

Comment: This works when you get 504 errors when running `brew update`.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://digitizor.com/2015/10/01/fix-homebrew-permissions-osx-el-capitan/) helped me after updating to El Capitan. In my case, `chown` wasn't working ("zsh: command not found: chown"), so step 1 was adding this line to my .zshrc:

`export PATH="$PATH:/usr/sbin"`

I'd already tried several of the more popular answers above, so I'm pretty sure that `git status` was coming up clean by the time I pasted in the critical command from the blog post:

`sudo chown $(whoami):admin /usr/local && sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local`

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
1. cd `brew --prefix`
2. git fetch origin
3. git reset --hard origin/master
4. sudo brew update
```

Comment: Fwiw, sudo is strongly discouraged when using homebrew. 

Note the down-votes on other answers to this question, as well as the warning homebrew helpfully provides when you enter a command using sudo. @A5308Y also provides a link to the FAQ about why sudo is bad; the latest version of that FAQ is at https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#why-does-homebrew-say-sudo-is-bad-

Have you tried following your steps without sudo?