# brew installation of hbase?

Tags: macos, hbase, homebrew

It appears brew DOES have a recipe for hbase, but it fails with a 404 when downloading hbase itself.

```
13:44:51/java:11 $brew install hbase
==> Downloading http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=hbase/hbase-0.94.11/hbase-0.94.11.tar.gz
==> Best Mirror http://apache.mirrors.tds.net/hbase/hbase-0.94.11/hbase-0.94.11.tar.gz

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Download failed: http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=hbase/hbase-0.94.11/hbase-0.94.11.tar.gz
```

A corrected url would be:   http://mirror.reverse.net/pub/apache/hbase/hbase-0.94.11/hbase-0.94.11.tar.gz

I am not experienced in creating/modifying brew recipes. Would this be a simple case of downloading/tweaking a brew recipe file for a correct hbase download url and then re-trying?  What would be the steps?

**Update**
Based on comments below i did

```
$brew update && brew upgrade
```

This failed for me:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    Library/Contributions/brew_bash_completion.sh
    Library/Contributions/brew_fish_completion.fish
    Library/Contributions/brew_zsh_completion.zsh
    Library/Contributions/cmd/brew-dirty.rb
    Library/Contributions/cmd/brew-leaves.rb
           ..
    Library/Formula/chruby.rb
    Library/Formula/cimg.
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    Library/Aliases/git-tig
    Library/Aliases/libtcnative
    Library/Contributions/cmd/brew-bundle.rb
         ..
    Library/Formula/vtclock.rb
    Library/Formula/x11vnc.rb
    Library/Formula/x265.rb
    Library/F
Aborting
Error: Failure while executing: git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Comment: I didn't need to do a `brew upgrade` -- the `brew update` was enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for how to fix brew update && brew upgrade , then following some instructions on [Brew update failed: untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113427/brew-update-failed) and doing some manual updating of permissions under /usr/local, I was able to install hbase.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me as well:

```
[ ~] brew install hbase
==> Installing hbase dependency: hadoop
==> Downloading http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=hadoop/core/hadoop-1.2
==> Best Mirror http://www.dsgnwrld.com/am/hadoop/core/hadoop-1.2.1/hadoop-1.2.1
############
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solved my problem, the code simply gets latest references from git

```
cd /usr/local && git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

or if it fails

```
cd /usr/local && sudo git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```