# Hybrid ISO Image Creator Tool?

Tags: windows, macos, iso

I'm currently automating some processes that my company uses to package drivers into ISO images.  The established route uses a tool called "CDEverywhere" because it creates a Mac partition and Windows partition AND shares common folders between the two.  Unfortunately, the company that made CDEverywhere has deprecated it's support for the tool, and there are potential licensing issues (Each installation needs a license and there isn't a way to obtain new licenses...)

Does anyone know of a decent alternative to CDEverywhere?  I've run through Google and found some tools, but none that accomplish what CDEverywhere does. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OS X` has [**hdiutil**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html), which can create `hybrid iso` images:

```
$ hdiutil makehybrid -iso -joliet -o image.iso /path/to/data
```

> - `image.iso` would be the name of the `iso` you are creating
> - `/path/to/data` is what will go on it.

↳ [hdiutil man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html)

Comment: Thanks very much, my teammate is looking for a solution via ubuntu, and I'm gonna tackle this OS x route. Appreciate it

Comment: This worked like a charm, found that you can hide folders to their respective file systems too.  However, on the windows partition of the .iso all the filenames/directory names are capitalized..?  I know linux has a option to maintain their original filenames, does mac have a similar one?  I've gone through the man page for hdiutil and just found `-default-volume-name` but it isn't what I was looking for.

Comment: Turns out `hdiutils` is rather limited when it comes to getting specific information from driver to .iso in an "identical" format.  I'm going to use the `cdrtools` and the included `mkisofs` tool instead to maintain the specifics that I need.  [cdrtools for mac](http://freecode.com/projects/cdrecord).  Additionally, you might need to update **homebrew** if you're installing via cmd line [brew update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113427/brew-update-failed).