# cannot bundle install nokogiri error RoR tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning RoR for the first time and I am stuck on this part of the tutorial
http://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-first_tests

Specifically in the beginning where I am supposed to configure this gem file. I know there are other more up to date versions out but I am trying to follow the tutorial with this specific version. My gemfile is the same as the one displayed in the link.

When I run: `bundle install --without production` I get:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sprockets-rails":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    sprockets-rails (2.1.3)

  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.0.5) ruby depends on
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0) ruby

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

I tried `bundle update` but I get:

```
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.2.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.2.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I tried `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'` but get:

```
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/bradfordli/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
-----
libiconv is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Comment: I think you are leaving out some details :o the zero to deploy chapter of the linked book doesn't show nokogiri at all.

Comment: @BenjaminUdinktenCate I dont recall ever seeing anything in the book regarding nokogiri =/ i can check again

Comment: @BenjaminUdinktenCate everything worked fine up until the beginning of chapter 3 =/

Comment: well if you really need it, have a look at http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html as the error message suggests. You probably need to install a package manager like homebrew or macports before you can install libiconv

Comment: @BenjaminUdinktenCate i followed the instructions to install nokogiri but libiconv is always missing even though I have it installed.

Comment: are you on mac/windows/linux ?

Comment: cool, try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528839/why-does-installing-nokogiri-on-mac-os-fail-with-libiconv-is-missing

it has several different possible solutions for solving the iconv problem on mac - you may have to try more than one to find the one that solves it for you.