# Failure to install nokogiri libiconv is missing on Yosemite Mac OS X 10.10

Tags: rubygems, nokogiri, osx-yosemite

Trying to install Nokogiri I’m getting the following error

```
Maxims-MacBook-Air:ScrapingTheApple maximveksler$ gem install nokogiri
Fetching: nokogiri-1.6.2.1.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/maximveksler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
-----
libiconv is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/maximveksler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/maximveksler/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/nokogiri-1.6.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/maximveksler/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.2.1/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [nokogiri install tutorial](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html) provides the solution:

```
# bash
brew unlink gcc
gem uninstall nokogiri
xcode-select --install
gem install nokogiri
```

If you don't have Xcode 6.1, yet, you may install it from the [apple developer download site](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/) (section *additional tools*), as described in [this blog post](https://medium.com/@Dom_T4/yosemite-homebrew-81695c3dac31).

Comment: I've done this several times now, every time forgetting that this is the easiest and quickest solution. Even if you have Xcode installed and you've been using it, running `Xcode-select --install` is still needed.

Comment: Works also with macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 16):

I suggest an update to Oskar's answer, replace MacOSX10.9.sdk to MacOSX10.10.sdk, tested on OS X 10.10

```
gem install nokogiri -- \
--with-iconv-lib=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/lib \
--with-iconv-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include
```

Comment: Finally a solution that works in Yosemite. Thank you @ryaneof.

Comment: I was trying to use http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#mac_os_x steps but it did't help. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I was successfull with:

```
gem install nokogiri -- \
--with-iconv-lib=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib \
--with-iconv-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include
```

Answer (score 6):

without brew and other stuff:

```
xcode-select --install 
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case I had upgraded Xcode and forgot to install the command line tools so install was not able to run compiler.

The following installs the command line tools:

> xcode-select --install

Answer (score 4):

Just in case if some one is still not able to resolve it as I do with the above mentioned solution, then this is the alternate

> gem install nokogiri -- --user-system-libraries

or using bundle

> bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
>
> bundle install

Thanks to http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be get nokogiri to install, not sure yet about the operational state.

```
brew install libiconv
gem install nokogiri -- --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/opt/libiconv/include/ --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/opt/libiconv/lib/
```

Install log:

```
Maxims-MacBook-Air:ScrapingTheApple maximveksler$ gem install nokogiri -- --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/opt/libiconv/include/ --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/opt/libiconv/lib/
Building native extensions with: '--with-iconv-include=/usr/local/opt/libiconv/include/ --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/opt/libiconv/lib/'
This could take a while...
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Building libxml2-2.8.0 for nokogiri with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Fix-parser-local-buffers-size-problems.patch
    - 0002-Fix-entities-local-buffers-size-problems.patch
    - 0003-Fix-an-error-in-previous-commit.patch
    - 0004-Fix-potential-out-of-bound-access.patch
    - 0005-Detect-excessive-entities-expansion-upon-replacement.patch
    - 0006-Do-not-fetch-external-parsed-entities.patch
    - 0007-Enforce-XML_PARSER_EOF-state-handling-through-the-pa.patch
    - 0008-Improve-handling-of-xmlStopParser.patch
    - 0009-Fix-a-couple-of-return-without-value.patch
    - 0010-Keep-non-significant-blanks-node-in-HTML-parser.patch
    - 0011-Do-not-fetch-external-parameter-entities.patch
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT!  Nokogiri builds and uses a packaged version of libxml2.

If this is a concern for you and you want to use the system library
instead, abort this installation process and reinstall nokogiri as
follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

However, note that nokogiri does not necessarily support all versions
of libxml2.

For example, libxml2-2.9.0 and higher are currently known to be broken
and thus unsupported by nokogiri, due to compatibility problems and
XPath optimization bugs.
************************************************************************
Building libxslt-1.1.28 for nokogiri with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Adding-doc-update-related-to-1.1.28.patch
    - 0002-Fix-a-couple-of-places-where-f-printf-parameters-wer.patch
    - 0003-Initialize-pseudo-random-number-generator-with-curre.patch
    - 0004-EXSLT-function-str-replace-is-broken-as-is.patch
    - 0006-Fix-str-padding-to-work-with-UTF-8-strings.patch
    - 0007-Separate-function-for-predicate-matching-in-patterns.patch
    - 0008-Fix-direct-pattern-matching.patch
    - 0009-Fix-certain-patterns-with-predicates.patch
    - 0010-Fix-handling-of-UTF-8-strings-in-EXSLT-crypto-module.patch
    - 0013-Memory-leak-in-xsltCompileIdKeyPattern-error-path.patch
    - 0014-Fix-for-bug-436589.patch
    - 0015-Fix-mkdir-for-mingw.patch
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT!  Nokogiri builds and uses a packaged version of libxslt.

If this is a concern for you and you want to use the system library
instead, abort this installation process and reinstall nokogiri as
follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install
************************************************************************
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.6.2.1
Parsing documentation for nokogiri-1.6.2.1
Installing ri documentation for nokogiri-1.6.2.1
Done installing documentation for nokogiri after 4 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Comment: The hyphen in your command right after `nokogiri` was wrong. This worked for me `gem install nokogiri -- --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/opt/libiconv/include/ --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/opt/libiconv/lib/`

Comment: @crcastle Fixed. Caused by Mac auto replace for text.

Answer (score 0):

on 10.9 with XCode 6.1 i had to throw in `--use-system-libraries` because the customized libxslt was dying.

`gem install nokogiri -- --with-iconv-lib=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib --with-iconv-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include --use-system-libraries`

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this problem as well, turns out for me it was a result of having installed macports under Mavericks, and not having migrating the setup to Yosemite.

Following the instructions here:

`http://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration`

Allowed me to install the older version of Nokogiri (1.5.x) that was a dependency of rspec-puppet

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, after installing command line tool,

```
gem install nokogiri -- --with-iconv-lib=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib --with-iconv-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include --use-system-libraries
```

Doesn't necessarily work as it keeps saying check the software update(it's already the latest version). Instead, I used `sudo gem install nokogiri --pre` which worked in the end