# Failed to change ruby version and rails in El Capitan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I installed `rbenv`. Then, I tried to install `ruby2.2.3` with it but `ruby2.2.3p173` is by default(I changed it almost half an year ago & don't remember with whom I did it: rbenv or rvm) on my mac. It doesn't change even if I try to change it, Don't know why. Without bothering about the version I tried to install rails but I get the below errors:

```
$ rbenv install 2.2.3
Downloading ruby-2.2.3.tar.gz...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/df795f2f99860745a416092a4004b016ccf77e8b82dec956b120f18bdc71edce
Installing ruby-2.2.3...
Installed ruby-2.2.3 to /Users/abhimanyuaryan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3

$ rbenv global 2.2.3
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin14]
$ gem install rails -v 4.2.4
Fetching: thread_safe-0.3.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.5
Fetching: tzinfo-1.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.2
Fetching: i18n-0.7.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.7.0
Fetching: activesupport-4.2.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-4.2.4
Fetching: rails-deprecated_sanitizer-1.0.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-deprecated_sanitizer-1.0.3
Fetching: mini_portile-0.6.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mini_portile-0.6.2
Fetching: nokogiri-1.6.6.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/g/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151009-78164-1jff7t7.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
-----
The file "/usr/include/iconv.h" is missing in your build environment,
which means you haven't installed Xcode Command Line Tools properly.

To install Command Line Tools, try running `xcode-select --install` on
terminal and follow the instructions.  If it fails, open Xcode.app,
select from the menu "Xcode" - "Open Developer Tool" - "More Developer
Tools" to open the developer site, download the installer for your OS
version and run it.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/g/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/g/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/g/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.2.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
$ rails -v 
-bash: /usr/local/bin/rails: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

***After trying the fix suggested in the comment by `Manuel van Rijn`***

***I followed all the step in the post shared by him.***

But, when type the last command i.e. `gem install nokogiri -- --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14`

I get the following errors + results ->

```
Last login: Fri Oct  9 14:59:31 on console
$ gem install nokogiri -- --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14
Building native extensions with: '--with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/g/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151009-71915-1k5omgj.rb extconf.rb --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv using --with-iconv-* flags... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.2
with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch
    - 0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.2.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.2... OK
Running patch with /Users/g/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxml2/0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running patch with /Users/g/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxml2/0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running 'install' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Activating libxml2 2.9.2 (from /Users/g/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0/libxml2/2.9.2)...
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxslt-1.1.28
with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Adding-doc-update-related-to-1.1.28.patch
    - 0002-Fix-a-couple-of-places-where-f-printf-parameters-wer.patch
    - 0003-Initialize-pseudo-random-number-generator-with-curre.patch
    - 0004-EXSLT-function-str-replace-is-broken-as-is.patch
    - 0006-Fix-str-padding-to-work-with-UTF-8-strings.patch
    - 0007-Separate-function-for-predicate-matching-in-patterns.patch
    - 0008-Fix-direct-pattern-matching.patch
    - 0009-Fix-certain-patterns-with-predicates.patch
    - 0010-Fix-handling-of-UTF-8-strings-in-EXSLT-crypto-module.patch
    - 0013-Memory-leak-in-xsltCompileIdKeyPattern-error-path.patch
    - 0014-Fix-for-bug-436589.patch
    - 0015-Fix-mkdir-for-mingw.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install
************************************************************************
Extracting libxslt-1.1.28.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0/ports/libxslt/1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/g/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0001-Adding-doc-update-related-to-1.1.28.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/g/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0002-Fix-a-couple-of-places-where-f-printf-parameters-wer.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/g/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0003-Initialize-pseudo-random-number-generator-with-curre.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/g/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0004-EXSLT-function-str-replace-is-broken-as-is.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/g/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0006-Fix-str-padding-to-work-with-UTF-8-strings.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/g/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0007-Separate-function-for-predicate-matching-in-patterns.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/g/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0008-Fix-direct-pattern-matching.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/g/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0009-Fix-certain-patterns-with-predicates.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/g/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0010-Fix-handling-of-UTF-8-strings-in-EXSLT-crypto-module.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/g/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0013-Memory-leak-in-xsltCompileIdKeyPattern-error-path.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/g/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0014-Fix-for-bug-436589.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/g/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0015-Fix-mkdir-for-mingw.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running 'configure' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running 'compile' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running 'install' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Activating libxslt 1.1.28 (from /Users/g/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0/libxslt/1.1.28)...
checking for main() in -llzma... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in libxml/parser.h... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -llibxml2... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  Please locate mkmf.log to investigate how it is failing.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/g/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build
    --with-xml2lib
    --without-xml2lib
    --with-libxml2lib
    --without-libxml2lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/g/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/g/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.2.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
$
```

**Just for verification...**

I have libxml2, libiconv, xcode command line tools installed and I have also created a symlink for the formulas using `brew link --forced $Forumula`

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6163052/959041

Comment: @ManuelvanRijn I have updated my question after trying what you suggested. Still no luck.

Comment: alright so this saidly seems to be some issue with libxml2... Although you say you've got it installed, something isn't working well because else your wouldn't get `libxml2 is missing.  Please locate mkmf.log to investigate how it is failing.` from the bundle install...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method:

1.Edit you ~/.bash_profile. Add a new PATH about ruby2.2.3 like this:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:"/Users/abhimanyuaryan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin"
```

2.Run this command to make it work:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Then try enter "ruby -v", osx will use the latest path to run ruby.

Comment: you posted too late. I re-installed the operating system and did a fresh installation at it worked. Anyways Thanks.